# Change css of master page runtime

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, branding, custom-masterpage

I got a requirement in which user should be able to change css of masterpage dynamically in sharpoint site.
One way I found is to read the content of master page, replace the css classes, so that the new class will be applied.But this does not suits my requirements as it changes the actual class name.

is there any other way to achieve this? How can I dynamically change css of master page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To can also use Jquery/Javascript for this

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className = "MyClass";
```

What you can do is put runat="server" tag to the element and create master page code behind class. and change the class name from code behind.

To add master page code behind you can refer: 
http://blog.nerdery.com/2013/04/tech-tips-creating-a-sharepoint-2010-master-page-with-code-behind/

Comment: But I don't want to change the master page or css file. I just want to replace the existing classname with new class name.

Comment: You want to change the class name for a specific element?

Comment: Yes, I want to change the css class name for specific element. For example suitbar.

Comment: So what you can do is put runat="server" tag to the element and create master page code behind class. and change the class name from code behind.

Comment: Can't we access it from user control which I load on masterpage?

Comment: Your control is on Master page. You need to find the control on whole page. You can try but i don't think you can easily find it.

Comment: You can try using Jquery to find element and then use addClass() method to add your class. For ex. $s('.ms-core-suiteLinkList').addClass('mycustomClass');

Comment: Let me try by adding the class name from javascript.

Comment: do you want to change the site theme? what exactly is the requirement?

Comment: The requirement is provide a page through user can specify color and font, images that are going to be used on page. Based on data provided by user, change the css file dynamically.

Comment: I'll update the css via jquery as you people have suggested. Or another way I can use is to update the actual css file via code based on the values provided by user.

Answer (score 0):

1) you can check the conditions or directly change the classes through user control using below c# code:

```
 if (condition)

    div.Attributes["class"] = "newClass";
```

2) using Jquery you can use the below code:

```
  $('div').removeClass("currentClass").addClass('newClass');
```